# UI-router dynamic state access level

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state setup like this. This serves dynamic pages from the database based on the :pageSlug via pageObj in the resolve.
I am wondering if its possible to make data.access on the state itself a dynamic variable as well, meaning the state would get its access property from the database.

```
    .state('site.home.page', {
        url: ':pageSlug',
        data: {
            access: AccessLevels.anon //make me dynamic! Can I access the resolve from here?
        },
        resolve: {
            pageObj : function($stateParams, REST, $state) {
                return REST.getOne("/page?slug="+$stateParams.pageSlug).then(function(rtnData) {
                    $state.current.data.access = rtnData.access; //this doesn't work, $state.current doesn't seem to be loaded?
                    return rtnData;
                });
            },
        },
```

For reference, I'm using a similar setup to this http://www.frederiknakstad.com/2013/01/21/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Turns out, $state isn't available in resolve or onEnter. A injectable $transition$ state is in the process of being integrated. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1257

Comment: The data is not dynamic. This code you show runs ONCE in the setup (config), so even if you could access the resolver, the data would be still there.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli You're right, so the other option would be pinging the DB every time in $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart') but that seems inefficient to me since I'm already pinging the DB in the resolve. Could I set data.access to some sort of global var that changes based on the resolve, therefore its dynamic for every page?

Comment: can you use the $rootScope there and cache (hardcoded/manually) the result? so you'd be hitting the DB only on expired or different result.

Comment: Actually, since I don't fully understand the issue/system/mdoel you have, I cannot completely help you. But you can cache the result in either bound of your system.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli Ill give that a shot. Thanks for the help, I'll try to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think the server should just return a proper HTTP status code when access is denied so you can handle it safely (and preventing data to go over the wire that should not be seen).

But assuming that is not an option, if I were you, I would create a service to store the ACL's that you receive from the server while resolving the pages, so something like:

(I'm typing this out of my head, so consider this more like meta code)

```
// Service to keep track of ACL's
.factory('aclService', [function(){
    var service = {},
        acls = {};

    service.setAcl = function(slug, acl){
        acls[slug] = acl;
    };

    service.getAcl = function(slug){
        return acls[slug] || 'access denied'; // or whatever you want to return by default
    };

    return service;
}]);
```

so you can use it to store the ACL when you receive it:

```
.state('site.home.page', {
    url: ':pageSlug',
    data: {
        access: AccessLevels.anon //make me dynamic! Can I access the resolve from here?
    },
    resolve: {
        pageObj : function($stateParams, REST, $state, aclService) {
            return REST.getOne("/page?slug="+$stateParams.pageSlug).then(function(rtnData) {

                // Store the ACL in the service
                aclService.setAcl($stateParams.pageSlug, rtnData.access);
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

and then consult the ACL to decide if you want to load the state or not:

```
// Listen to the SUCCESS event
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){

    var acl = aclService.getAcl(toParams.pageSlug);

    // Do whatever check is needed to verify access
    if(toState.data.access !== acl){

        // Do whatever you like to do here when access is denied
        // The state is already loaded but you can redirect the user away
    }
});
```

Since you're using a service to store a cache of ACL, you could further optimize and also add an additional check before the state is transitioned to, like:

```
// Listen to the START event here
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){

    var acl = aclService.getAcl(toParams.pageSlug);

    // Return early if no cache is found
    if(acl === undefined){
        return;
    }

    // Do whatever check is needed to verify access
    if(toState.data.access !== acl){

        // Do whatever you like to do here when access is denied
        // The state will no longer be loaded now
    }
});
```

If you really want to take it to the extreme, you could preload the aclService with all ACL's when bootstrapping your AngularJS application so you have a hot cache to start with.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Note: `$stateParams` will not be set to the you are going to in the resolve function (it will be the params for the current page that you are coming from). https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/state.js#L867 is where the resolve happens, https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/state.js#L908 is where the values are copied (which happens later).

Comment: @jvanddemo thanks this is a really really helpful answer. I think your first sentence says it best however, I'm going to take care of the server side first then revisit this and see what I have to do on the frontend. Thank you!

Comment: @DaveChenell Good call, that's the best way indeed! Good luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

when `$state.current.data.access = rtnData.access;` runs, `$state.current` is the state that you are coming from, not going to.  `$state.current` only gets changed after everything has resolved.

You may want to log `$state.current` there to see if it is what you think it should be and not from the ~previous state (that you are coming from).  Same with `$stateParams`.

Depending on when you need to access the data, you can set it up in the `$stateChangeSuccess` event.

Comment: As you predicted, $state.current is pretty busted in resolve and onEnter, not exactly sure why.

Comment: It isn't "busted", it works as designed.  $state.current is the "from state" until the transition promise is resolved.  If the transition is rejected (e.g., in onEnter), $state.current doesn't change. We're in process of adding an injectable object called '$transition$' which will provide the to/from states, as well as the transition promise.  You will be able to inject this into onEnter/controllers, etc.  Follow https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1257 or use the undocumented $transition$ preview in UI-Router Extras http://bit.ly/1vh18xd

Comment: @ChrisT Sorry busted was the wrong word there. $transition$ sounds great, thanks for the link. I will follow the github issue, appreciate it.